# Node.js, Express and MySQL. Require is not defined

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm using node.js, express and mysql in one of my projects, however when I call mysql it's shows me an error telling "[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require".

```js
//server.js

class SQL{
  constructor(){
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : '',
      database : 'newDB'
    });
  }
  connect(){
    this.connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Connected');
    });
  }
  disconnect(){
    this.connection.end(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('error ending connection: ' + err.stack);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Connection ended');
    });
  }
}


// main.js 

function main(){
  var database = new SQL();
}

main();
```

Before installing express it was working fine but after I installed express it shows me the error.

The class and the function are in separate files.

Comment: what command do you run to get this error?

Comment: nodemon ./bin/www

Comment: That's only a piece of code, I'm using express, node.js and mysql

Comment: That's a strange error for `require`. You are using require as function but the error is like for a variable. Try to put the require above in your file

Comment: I already try that and gives me the same error

Comment: could you add more piece of code, how `registerUser` is called or something?

Comment: I have a javascript file with multiple functions. In one function I call "registerUser".

Comment: separate this function in it's own empty project and try to run it. I think your error is from somewhere else.

Comment: I'll add more code